# GNU Screen: -S option doesn't work when launched from bash script

Tags: bash, ssh, gnu, gnu-screen

Having such simple bash script:

```
/bin/bash
screen -dm -S "backup"
wget -O backup-$(date +%Y-%m-%d).txt http://link-to-very-huge-file/
```

The problem is: when `screen -dm -S "backup"` executes, new screen session appears. But it's not named! When I (from ssh) do `screen -ls` it gives me:

> ```
> (10/09/2011 04:35:05 PM)        (Detached)
> 1969.VNC        (10/09/2011 01:53:45 PM)        (Detached)
> 910.minecraft   (10/09/2011 12:59:29 PM)        (Detached)
> ```

I've created the last two myself. But the first one, created by bash script, doesn't have name and even doesn't have id!

When I do `screen -dm -S "backup"` myself, it works fine and gives me the named screen session:

> ```
> 3527.backup (10/09/2011 04:44:40 PM)        (Detached)
> ```

But why script does bad? How to make it work propertly?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's odd; it works for me.

Can you copy-and-paste the *exact* contents of the bash script?  The one in your question is missing the `#!` on the first line, and has the `wget` command on a line following the `screen` command.  This makes me suspect the problem is in some code you haven't shown us.

Here's what I just tried.  (I added the `-c /dev/null` to avoid loading my fairly elaborate `.screenrc` file):

```
$ screen -ls
There is a screen on:
        2454.pts-1.kvetch       (09/09/2011 11:00:03 AM)        (Detached)
1 Socket in /var/run/screen/S-kst.

$ cat foo.bash
#!/bin/bash

screen -dm -S FROM_BASH -c /dev/null sleep 12345
$ ./foo.bash
$ screen -ls
There are screens on:
        10384.FROM_BASH (10/09/2011 01:22:48 PM)        (Detached)
        2454.pts-1.kvetch       (09/09/2011 11:00:03 AM)        (Detached)
2 Sockets in /var/run/screen/S-kst.

$
```

I'm using screen 4.00.03jw4 on Ubuntu 11.04.